# Holding scala type in variable

Tags: scala

I need to pass to `asInstanceOf` a type parameter dynamically. How can I do that?

This is the best I managed to do:

```
val fieldLength = 4
var dType: Class[Any] = null

fieldLength match {
    case 4 =>
        dType = Int.getClass

    case 8 =>
        dType = Double.getClass
}

val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(fieldLength)
    .putInt(row.get(i).asInstanceOf[dType])
```

But obviously this code doesn't compile.

Comment: `ByteBuffer.putInt()` won't take a `Double` as the passed parameter.

Comment: Looks like a classic [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your design is `putInt` only allows Int to be passed, but you are trying to pass both Int and Double, which won't work.

A common way to design this is caching the put function instead of the class type, e.g.

```
val fieldLength = 4
val putObj = (buf: ByteBuffer, obj: Any) => fieldLength match {
    case 4 =>
        buf.putInt(obj.asInstanceOf[Int])
    case 8 =>
        buf.putDouble(obj.asInstanceOf[Double])
    //other cases or catch all
}

val byteBuffer = putObj(ByteBuffer.allocate(fieldLength), row.get(i))
```

You can even make this into an implicit class to make it more pretty, or even make it into type class, but the core concept is to cache the function while keeping a functional programming in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `asInstanceOf` is not going to work unless the type of the value returned by `get` is the one that you expect. So it is better to `match` on the type of that value for safety:

```
val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(fieldLength)

row.get(i) match {
  case int: Int =>
    byteBuffer.putInt(i)
  case double: Double =>
    byteBuffer.putDouble(double)
}
```